# Search through a table in R?

Tags: r

I'm new to using R and I'm trying to find something from a table. I have a table that is read using read.table(), like this:

```
A  1
B  2
C  3
D  4
```

Given a query, say "C", I need to find the corresponding element from the second column. How can I iterate through the elements in the first column to find which row contains "C", then extract "3" from the second column?

Thanks! :)

Comment: What is the exact structure of your variable (use `str()` and copy/paste the result here)?

Comment: @BenBolker Imagine that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends whether the first column shown above is really a column or whether it represents the row names.

If your data object is `X` then if the former (no row names):

```
X[X[,1]=="C",2]
```

or if the latter (row names)

```
X["C",2]
```

The stuff before the comma indexes the rows, the stuff after the comma indexes the columns. With respect, this question indicates that it would be **extremely valuable** to go read the "Introduction to R" that comes with R (or almost any other basic R text) ...

Comment: Thanks for actually helping me -- I'm really stressed out and am having trouble figuring out a lot of the basics on my own. I have been reading the manual but it's a lot to absorb at once.